# Comparing enumeration flags (bit combinations) with linq

Tags: c#, linq, enums, flags

I have an enumeration declared as such

```
[Flags]
public enum PermissionEnum
{
    [EnumStringValue("None")]
    None = 0x0,
    [EnumStringValue("Create")]
    Create = 0x1,
    [EnumStringValue("Edit")]
    Edit = 0x2,
    [EnumStringValue("View")]
    View = 0x4
}
```

I subsequently have some linq that attempts to obtain the highest permission available.

```
List<SecurityRolePermissionView> AvailablePermissions = GetPermissions();

SecurityRolePermissionView HighestPermission = AvailablePermissions.OrderByDescending(o => o.Permission).FirstOrDefault();
```

With the current enumeration values this seems to do what it suggests it will do. However, I am pretty confident that this code is incorrect but I'm not sure I could explain why or how to achieve a correct implementation.

Either way, could someone please be kind enough to confirm if this is in-fact incorrect (and why) and provide an explanation of how to achieve my desired result?

**EDIT: I might not have been clear enough in explaining what my highest permission is. This is a flags enumeration. Therefore it can contain any combination of None, Create, Edit, View. What I am looking to find as the highest is basically Create + Edit + View. If that Fails, Edit + View and lastly View**

Comment: What does it mean to have "highest permission available"? Is View greater than Edit because that's your sample would give you.

Comment: Fair point but as this is a bit combination and I never have View vs Edit - It would always be View + Edit or View + Create, I'm guessing thats why its working?

Comment: What if `AvailablePermissions` has two elements one with Edit and another with View, what should be returned? The `SecurityRolePermissionView` with View or Edit?

Comment: Why do you think the code is incorrect?  Do you consider "Create+Edit" to be "higher permission" than "View"?

Comment: I guess I would argue edit but that scenario isnt supposed to happen as specified above, so the behaviour can be undefined...

Comment: Its incorrect because as mike z point out above his exact scenario View VS Edit would (I assume) return Edit but more specifically its not that I know its incorrect. Im not sure what the resulting bit combinations are going to be and as a result I cant be confident that it IS CORRECT. My gut tells me it isn't and that the fact its working is only a result of the specific implementation of my enumeration.

Comment: @Maxim Right. If you have some way to guarantee that you never have a value with only Edit, it works for that case. So what are the valid values?

Comment: None, View + Edit, View + Create, View + Edit + Create

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Enum ordering is the same as the ordering of the enum's underlying type (C# specification section 7.9.5, "Enumeration operators").  Therefore, this is the order of your possible enum values:

```
View | Edit | Create ( = 7)
View | Edit          ( = 6)
View | Create        ( = 5)
View                 ( = 4)
Edit | Create        ( = 3)
Edit                 ( = 2)
Create               ( = 1)
None                 ( = 0)
```

If that ordering fits with your requirements, then your code is correct.

Comment: BAM! This explains it perfectly and really helped me have a eureka moment. Up until now I wasn't actually sure that the numbers I was seeing in the IDE were what is being represented underneath - No idea why... Anyway, thank you so much...

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if there is any direct conversion function available from octal to int.

You can create one funciton which returns int value when we pass Enumeration value.
For example,
 `GetIntValue(PermissionEnum.None)` 
This will return 0;

So you can write the ordering logic as follows:

```
SecurityRolePermissionView HighestPermission = AvailablePermissions.OrderByDescending(o => GetIntValue(o.Permission)).FirstOrDefault();
```